# How can I edit the contents of my clipboard in vim?

Tags: os-clipboard

Often while editing (say, a post on this network), I find myself wanting to copy something, edit it, and paste it back.

At other times, I have some text in my clipboard, but isn't perfect. I would like a quick way to edit it and place it back in the clipboard for pasting.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

### Command-line tools

For the purposes of this sections, I'm going to assume you have a command line tool(s) which

- output the clipboard on stdout (`clippaste`)
- reads stdin and places it in the clipboard (`clipcopy`)

With these, you can use

#### [vipe](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) (available with moreutils)

vipe is the pipe editor (it uses your actual `EDITOR`, so it doesn't have to be vim).

Run at a shell:

```
clippaste | vipe | clipcopy
```

#### Manual vipe:

Run at a shell:

```
clippaste > /tmp/clip
vim /tmp/clip # in bash, you can abbreviate as 'vim !$'
clipcopy < /tmp/clip
```

#### clippaste and clipcopy

By OS:

- macOS: `pbpaste` and `pbcopy`
- *nix: `xclip -selection c -o` and `xclip -selection c`
- *nix: `xsel` (?)

### Registers

In vim, use the clipboard register:

```
:enew | put * | 0delete
```

Then

```
:%yank * | bdelete
```

Comment: I welcome edits regarding clipboard tools for other OS

Answer (score 2):

So long as your Vim is built with `+clipboard`, [you can do this from the shell without external tools](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/98jq2p/vimclip_poor_mans_vimanywhere/e4meunj/?context=8&depth=9). Try the command:

```
vim +'pu+' +'$d' +'au BufWriteCmd vimclippy %y+ | set nomodified' vimclippy
```

*N.B. I'm using the `"+` register for the clipboard. Use the `"*` register in the `:put` and `:yank` commands to edit the primary/selection instead.*

Instead of saving a file when you write the buffer, the changes will be saved back into the clipboard (and [`'modified'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27modified%27) will be unset so you can quit without Vim complaining the changes are unsaved. Using [`buftype=nofile`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27buftype%27) is an alternative implementation).

You can alias this so that you can run it simply by typing `vimclippy`. e.g. in bash:

```
alias vimclippy="vim +'pu+' +'\$d' +'au BufWriteCmd vimclippy %y+ | set nomodified' vimclippy"
```

Comment: Neat to see a « pure vim » solution! My use of the shell tends to fit the `pbcopy | vipe | pbpaste` idiom more—pipelines are just too dang cool—but +1 from me

Comment: Correction: `pbpaste | vipe | pbcopy`